# Set Operation `intersection` and return only one gdf

Tags: python, geopandas, intersection, overlay

I would like to find all polygons that intersect and return the original polygons; not the intersection. Lets go with the [set operation example](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/set_operations.html)

```py
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

polys1 = geopandas.GeoSeries([Polygon([(0,0), (2,0), (2,2), (0,2)]),
                              Polygon([(2,2), (4,2), (4,4), (2,4)])])
polys2 = geopandas.GeoSeries([Polygon([(1,1), (3,1), (3,3), (1,3)])])


df1 = geopandas.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': polys1, 'df1':[1,2]})
df2 = geopandas.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': polys2, 'df2':[5]})

ax = df1.plot(color='red');
df2.plot(ax=ax, color='green', alpha=0.5);
```

[image]

```py
res_intersection = df1.overlay(df2, how='intersection')
res_intersection
    df1 df2 geometry
0   1   5   POLYGON ((2.00000 2.00000, 2.00000 1.00000, 1....
1   2   5   POLYGON ((2.00000 2.00000, 2.00000 3.00000, 3....
```

```py
res_intersection.plot()
```

[image]

The geometry of the intersecting polygons are different (to the original). I want the original geometry of `df1` that intersect `df2` please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can spatial join df2 to df1 and then select:

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
import geopandas as gpd

polys1 = gpd.GeoSeries([Polygon([(0,0), (2,0), (2,2), (0,2)]),
                              Polygon([(2,2), (4,2), (4,4), (2,4)])])
polys2 = gpd.GeoSeries([Polygon([(1,1), (3,1), (3,3), (1,3)])])


df1 = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': polys1, 'df1':[1,2]})
df2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': polys2, 'df2':[5]})

ax = df1.plot(color='red');
df2.plot(ax=ax, color='green', alpha=0.5);


df1["id1"] = range(df1.shape[0]) #Create a unique id column to later select by

#Inner join df2 to df1 to drop all rows in df1 except those intersecting df2
sj = gpd.sjoin(left_df=df1[["id1","geometry"]], right_df=df2[["geometry"]], how="inner", predicate="intersects")

df3 = df1.loc[df1["id1"].isin(sj["id1"])] #Select by id1
df3.plot(ax=ax, color="blue", alpha=0.5)
```

[image]